# Is there any option to connect XDTouch IrTouchScreen to Arduino?

Tags: usb, rs232

Is there any option to connect XDTouch IrTouchScreen with USB interface or RS232 to Arduino board?

At the cable of this touchscreen i have something like at the photo.
At the top of the photo pins (+, t, r, -) from touchscreen to [SP232EEN](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/189641/SIPEX/SP232EEN.html), and at the bottom of photo pins (+, D-, D+, -) from CY7C63803-SXC module to USB output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your touch screen may talk RS-232. It uses the SP232EEN (a MAX232 clone) to interface with an MCU (Cypress CY7C63803) to get USB.

Connect wires to T1 IN and R1 OUT (I assume it's on channel 1) to your Arduino for UART communication. You would most likely need to disconnect those pins from talking to the Cypress chip, or they will interfere. Use the +5V and GND pins of the USB interface to power it direct from the Arduino.

Alternatively cut that board off and use a cheap MAX232 interface board to connect to the Arduino - that may be cheaper.  T and R are TX and RX (though from which PoV is anyone's guess).

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. I disconnect board from cable and I connect to FTDI RS232 module via RX and TX wire.
Red(+) ------>  5V FTDI module, 
Blue(T) ------>  RX FTDI module, 
Yellow(R) ------>  TX FTDI module, 
Black(-) ------>  GND FTDI module
And when I touch touchscreen in response I get weird data.
I checked response at all popular baudrate and nothing.

Comment: Example response from touchscreen on 9600 baud [example response](http://imgur.com/a/SdnaW)

Comment: Your typical FTDI board **ISN'T** RS-232. It's UART. RS-232 uses inverted NRZ high voltage (10V) logic and **RISKS DAMAGING YOUR FTDI BOARD**. **DISCONNECT IT NOW**.  You need a ***MAX232 BASED BOARD LIKE I STATED IN MY ANSWER***

Comment: Ok I see. I bought MAX232EPE 5V and i connect to touchscreen like in this [schema](http://imgur.com/a/rg9eo) and FTDI connect to my computer. Is this connection is ok? I'm asking because I'm afraid I can break something.

Comment: If the MAX232EPE you have is an entire module with the required boost capacitors etc then yes, that is fine. If it's just a bare chip you will need more components to get it to work.